# last object being printed regardless

Tags: java

I have this Person class with some methods to add, remove and view your friends. For some reason, when I want to view my friend, even though I think I'm calling the right methods the right way, The last Person object (which is carl ) is printed regardless of the object specifications in the method call. What is the problem?

here is the code:

```
package person;

public class Person {
    private static String name;
    private static String friends;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person ted = new Person ("ted");
        Person jim = new Person ("jim");
        Person todd = new Person ("todd");
        Person tom = new Person ("tom");
        Person carl = new Person ("carl");

        // apparently I'm making a mistake here... 
        jim.addFriend(zack);
        System.out.println(jim.getFriends());
    }
    public Person (String aName) {
        name = aName;
        friends = "";
    }
    public static void addFriend(Person friend) {

        friends = friends + friend.name + " ";
    }
    public static void unFriend (Person nonFriend) {
        friends = friends.replace(nonFriend.name + " ", "");
    }
    public static String getFriends () {
        return friends;
    }

}
```

Comment: Because they are `static` try removing that. `Static` pretty much means it is the same for all instances created of that class.

Comment: Remove all the static except for main. A static field will exist only once, is a field of the class object, and one could do `Person.name = "any";`

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/q/7026507/1079354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using static variable. Please try this.

```
package person;

public class Person {
    private  String name;
    private  String friends;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Person ted = new Person ("ted");
        Person jim = new Person ("jim");
        Person todd = new Person ("todd");
        Person tom = new Person ("tom");
        Person carl = new Person ("carl");

        // apparently I'm making a mistake here... 
        jim.addFriend(zack);
        System.out.println(jim.getFriends());
    }
    public Person (String aName) {
        name = aName;
        friends = "";
    }
    public void addFriend(Person friend) {

        friends = friends + friend.name + " ";
    }
    public void unFriend (Person nonFriend) {
        friends = friends.replace(nonFriend.name + " ", "");
    }
    public String getFriends () {
        return friends;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make

```
private static String name;
private static String friends;
```

To

```
private String name;
private String friends;
```

and change methods by removing `static` too

```
   public void addFriend(Person friend) {

        friends = friends + friend.name + " ";
    }
    public void unFriend (Person nonFriend) {
        friends = friends.replace(nonFriend.name + " ", "");
    }
    public String getFriends () {
        return friends;
    }
```